# Javascript -Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: javascript

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Assignment 7</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style7.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <h1>List King</h1>
        <h2 id="noteEntered">Audio Note</h2>
        <form action="example.org/">;
            <label for="noteInput">Enter note name:</label> 
            <input type="text" id="noteInput" />
            <div id="buttons">
                <a data-state="record" href="">record</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="javascript/assg07.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var usersName, noteEntered, textInput, targetName;

usersName.addEventListener("input", writeLabel, false);
```

in the last line with "usersName.addEventListener("input", writeLabel, false);" there is an error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined"

Comment: The reason is that you're never selecting an element to bind an event to. Could you post the username input html please?

Comment: There is no HTML to bind to the usersName...

Comment: So there's no HTML at all?

Comment: There's no HTML that seems like the user's name and you're not trying to select anything so it's going to error out. I'd try taking a look here to learn how to select elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use global object properties set up with the same names as HTML element `id` values. This is provided for in standards and not incorrect. However you then redefine the same identifier names as variables in the line

```
var usersName, noteEntered, textInput, targetName;
```

which initializes the variables to `undefined` because they don't have an initializer in the declaration. The declaration takes precedence and is **not changed or re-initialized** if HTML element ids are encountered later in the HTML file with the same `id` as the variable name.

Additionally if the `var` declaration is executed in global scope, it **replaces** window properties of the same name (so including the script after the HTML doesn't work either).

You need to, at least, remove `usersName` and `nodeEntered` from this variable declaration list to allow the global properties with those names to be given HTML element values.

There are alternatives such as using `let` instead of `var` followed by accessing elements as *properties* of the global object ( e.g. `window.usersName`), or to use `document.getElementById( idValue)` to access elements. The later method is the most common.

Answer (score -1):

First you should check for the existance of the variable usersName.

```
if (typeof usersName !== undefined) {
// here your code
}
```